# dealloc not fired when replacing scenes in Cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

For some reason the dealloc of my CCLayer is not fired when replacing the scene. Here is the code to replace the scene:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCFadeTransition transitionWithDuration:2.0f scene:[HelloWorld scene]]];
```

The above code is triggered when I press a button.

I have placed a NSLog inside the dealloc method which is never triggered.

UPDATE 1:

I ended up solving the problem by manually releasing the memory just before replacing the scene.

Comment: It sounds that the scene which was replaced by HelloWorld scene was not released. How do you instantiate the scene and how does it have your CCLayer instance?

Comment: means something is retaining the layer..

Comment: Did you pass any reference of current layer to any other object ? 
something like Layer = currentLayer ?

Comment: @Lim Gim Hong, I did passed a reference of the layer to other class.

Answer (score 6):

When I first time begun to use cocos2d I had encountered this exactly same problem.
In my case I'm added as targeted delegate the self and that means that reference count to the self was increased.

`[[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:2]swallowsTouches:NO];`

And I solved this by removing all delegates(also you can specify particular delegate) :

`[[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] removeAllDelegates];`

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post at cocos2d-iphone forum](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/11231), you just need to call `self.isTouchEnabled = YES;` in the `init` method to enable Cocos2D's to automatically call `removeDelegate:` method on the CCTouchDispatcher. Basically the following code should suffice:

```
- (void)init {
   // do the usual [super init] stuff


   self.isTouchEnabled = YES; // don't forget the self prefix!

   return self;
}

- (void)registerWithTouchDispatcher {
   [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:2 swallowsTouches:NO]; 
}
```

No need for `onEnter` and `onExit` as they should be handled automatically if you use `self.isTouchEnabled = YES;`

Comment: You might be answering a part of the question, but you're not clarifying why. It seems to me that the question is about managing the scene's memory, and I am not 100% sure, but it sounds like you are saying that the scene is adding itself as a touch delegate. Thus, the touch dispatcher is holding onto it. I'm running into the same problem as @azamsharp, and I'm more curious as to why manually setting "isTouchEnabled" will cause the scene to be released properly.